# Trouble submitting iOS App using LiveSDK

Tags: ios8, app-store-connect, onedrive, live-sdk

I want to submit my App to the Apple App Store today, however I'm having some trouble when I attempt to "Validate" my archive before submitting from the organizer.

My app is using the LiveSDK (specifically to use One Drive) but during validation I get the following error message:

```
iTunes Store operation failed.
Invalid Info.plist value. The value for the key 'MinimumOSVersion' in bundle MyApp.app/LiveSDK.framework is invalid. The minimum value is 8.0.
```

I have no idea how to fix this and any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple recently decided to stop allowing the simulator architectures to be included in the submission to the iTunes store.  The LiveSDK framework is built with the simulator architectures, for a work around please include the LiveSDK source directly.  You can find steps [here](https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK-for-iOS#22-to-reference-the-ios-api-source-code-directly).  There are more details in the discussion around this GitHub [issue](https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK-for-iOS/issues/43).